# jQuery post not loading from PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Ok so I have a link created with JS:

```
var content = document.getElementById("Profile");
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.innerHTML= ' <a href="eventList2.html" onclick ="post()"> Click Me </a>';
    content.appendChild(entry); 

function post(){
$.post( "random.php", { variable: "hello"} );
}
```

And in my PHP:

random.php

```
<?php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

$variable   = $_POST['variable'];   
echo"alert($variable);";

?>
```

"undefined" gets echoed instead of "hello". Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm not too familiar with AJAX and Jquery, I'm just going by whatever I see in tutorials and examples. Thanks

Comment: you never defined the variable `hello`. `alert(hello)` is what php is returning.

Comment: Yea as Kevin said you should put single quotes around it like `echo "alert('$variable')";`

Comment: when I tried that nothing alerts

Comment: I don't see where you Javascript is executing the returned value from the AJAX call. Did you forget to copy that into the question?

Comment: @Barmar the js writes a link to one of my webpages and when i click the link, the HTML "eventList2" run the PHP script, now, assuming, when i click the link my PHP file supposed to get the variable. When I test it using the echo statement. I get "undefined"

Comment: You need to show that code, it's not clear what you're doing from the explanation. I don't see how the echo from `random.php` is supposed to get into `eventList2.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Why have PHP return an alert? This is a bad approach. 
Let PHP return the json encoded result and have jquery handle the alert.
This is one possible way to achieve this:

```
$.post( "random.php", { variable: "hello"}, function(data) {
    alert(data);    
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

$variable   = $_POST['variable'];   
echo json_encode($variable);

?>
```

Comment: tried this but now I'm getting null instead of undefined..any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
echo"alert($variable);";
```

to:

```
$js = json_encode($variable);
echo "alert($js);";
```

This will put the contents of `$variable` into the proper format for a Javscript literal.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I tried this and now I'm only getting null

Comment: Do you still have `$variable = $_POST['variable']` before my code?